# html standard deviation code

Tags: html, standard-deviation, formula-editor

I am trying to code this formula (standard deviation):

```
       ____________  
   δ =√∑(xi - µ)2
            n
```

My html code is:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="180">
    <tr>
        <th width="180" colspan="3"><p align="center"><strong>Population Standard Deviation</strong></p></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td width="40" valign="top"><p align="center">&nbsp;</p></td>
       <td width="50" rowspan="4"><p align="right">&radic;</p></td>
       <td width="90" valign="bottom"><p align="left">__________</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="60" rowspan="2"><p align="centre"><strong> &#948; =</strong></p></td>
        <td  width="90"><p align="center"><strong>∑(x<sub>i</sub> -µ)<sup>2</sup></strong></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="90"><p align="center">n</p></td>
    </tr>
```

The challenge I have is to get the formula to be well positioned. I was thinking the row height would help but from further reading the row and column span would nullify it. So how can I best present this formula? 
I also have a challenge in adding the division line right below the summation (row3). I tried using CSS but it would mean having the subscripts and superscripts underlined. Is there a better code for this as well? Thanks.

Comment: It might be worth your time looking at [MathML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML) which is markup language for 'describing mathematical notations' which is a W3C Standard and part of HMTL5

Comment: Thanks AeroX for your quick response, I will certainly do so.